# How to retrigger focusRequester.requestFocus() when coming back to a composable?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, android-keypad

I have a MyBasicTextField in a composable to request user input:

```
@Composable
fun MyBasicTextField() {
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val focusRequester = remember{ FocusRequester() }

    BasicTextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .focusRequester(focusRequester),
        keyboardActions = keyboardActions ?: KeyboardActions(onAny = { keyboardController?.hide() }),

    )

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }
}
```

The keyboard automatically slides in when showing this composable, always.

But wherever `MyBasicTextField` is used:

- I tap on a LinkifiedText to leave and open a browser to show link
- I tap **BACK**
- and come back to previous MyBasicTextField screen, the keyboard is not shown
- also the `focusRequester.requestFocus()` is not triggered again when coming back

How can I solve my issue?

Comment: Post the calling site of this Composable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a top-level variable in your activity, then modify it from within the `onStart` overridden method. Use that variable as the key for `LaunchedEffect` in place of Unit. That variable basically keeps track of when the user enters the app.

`var userIn by mutableStateOf (true)`

In your Composable,

```
Launched effect(userIn){
  if(userIn && isKeyboardShown){
    ...
  }
}
```

Boring,

Answer (score 0):

You can use my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73660219/how-to-always-redraw-a-composable) as well, but instead of incrmenting the launchKey every time it's called, only increment the launchKey once user clicks on the browser link, that way it will not pop up during other re-compositions.